# Entity Framework Caching Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, catch-all

I am new to Entity Framework.

I have get to some values in my database using EF. It returns perfectly, and the values are shown in labels. But When I delete all values in my table (without using EF), the EF query is returning my old values. I know the EF stores the values in cache and returns the cached data for subsequent runs. Is this correct?

So how can I solve the problem when I have deleted all values in my database, but EF returns the old values?

**Edit**:

Now i used `datamodel.SaveChanges()`. But now also it's returning the same old values.

My sample query is look like below:

```
SchoolBriefcaseEntities datamodel = new SchoolBriefcaseEntities();
datamodel.SaveChanges();
List<Compliance> compliance=new List<Compliance>();
IList<ComplianceModel> complianceModel;
if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin"))
{
    compliance = datamodel.Compliances.Where(c => c.School.DistrictId == districtId).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Did you call `.SaveChanges();` on your dbContext? If you didn't the entities won't be removed..

Comment: Please Read my full question . I did't use delete in code.I deleted values in  straightly Database

Comment: How about your context? Open context when you need it and close it as soon as you're done. (You might want to improve your question, it's not clear at all)

Comment: did you restart your application ? what is the scope of your dbcontext ?

Comment: When you deleted your data from database (without using EF) did you called SaveChanges() or your dbContext was still active?

Comment: @Rob .Please See My Edit question.I was use SaveChanges().But no luck

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you know that changes happened outside of EF and want to refresh your ctxt for a specific entity, you can call **[ObjectContext.Refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx)**

```
datamodel.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, orders);
```

If this seems like it will be a common occurrence, you should disable object caching in your queries:

```
SchoolBriefcaseEntities datamodel = new SchoolBriefcaseEntities();
datamodel.tblCities.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
```

or to turn off object level caching for specific Entity:

```
Context.Set<Compliances>().AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: .AsNoTracking() for me

Comment: If AsNoTracking() is used, then DBContext won't Track changes to the Enetities. In which case, you won't be able to modify Entities and Save them using dbContext.SaveChanges() .

Comment: @AbhijeetNagre You can, it seems. You just need to manually attach the entity to the context and set its state, at least according to other sources on the topic.

Comment: @Zero3.  That's a bit of a contradiction. As soon as you said "you just need to..." you're creating an exceptional case. What Abhijeet said is correct. When you use AsNoTracking, you're loading an entity without registering it in the change tracker. Modifications to the entity will not be saved with SaveChanges.  If you want to save the changes to the entity instance, you need to essentially undo your AsNoTracking by manually adding the entity to the context's change tracker by calling Attach.  Only after doing that will changes to the entity be saved with SaveChanges.

Comment: @Triynko Hmm. I think this is version of "Is the glass half empty or half full?". At least now both sides have been represented ;).

Answer (score 20):

EF will not load changes unless you re query the context. EF queries db and loads maps them into objects, it watches changes you perform on objects and not on the database. EF does not track changes made directly to database and it will never track.

You have loaded a List, that List is your cache in memory. Even calling Save Changes will not refresh. You will have to query the context once again, that is create new list.

To see changes You will have to execute following line once more,

```
datamodel.Compliances.Where(c => c.School.DistrictId == districtId).ToList()
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you should follow some of the other solutions here, but it seems like you're wanting to clear the cache. You can achieve this by doing the following:

```
var count = datamodel.Compliances.Local.Count; // number of items in cache (ex. 30)

datamodel.Compliances.Local.ToList().ForEach(c => {
    datamodel.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Detached;
});

count = datamodel.Compliances.Local.Count; // 0
```

Comment: This was the best solution for the problem. Simply clear the cache of the DbContext and you are good to go.

Comment: @David - Restating in other words, you are basically suggesting to detach the object you will want to reflect the change. This way you suggest that the EntityManager will retrieve the object again when needed. Am I right ?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to use some MergeOption to all EntitieSet after create the context, like this:

```
var objSetProps = ctx.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObjectSet<>));
foreach (PropertyInfo objSetProp in objSetProps)
{
    ObjectQuery objSet = (ObjectQuery)objSetProp.GetValue(ctx, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null);
    objSet.MergeOption = MergeOption.PreserveChanges;
}
```

Read about the MergeOption here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption.aspx
Your will use NoTracking, I think.

If you want to CLEAR the "cached" entities, detaching it.

```
var entidades = Ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged);
foreach (var objectStateEntry in entidades)
    Ctx.Detach(objectStateEntry.Entity);
```

Where Ctx are my Context.

Comment: If I understand well your suggestion, you are saying that detaching an object from its EntityManager, when requested again, the EntityManager will get it again from database. Am I right ?

Comment: @Victor exactly!

Answer (score 4):

Below code helped my object to be refreshed with fresh database values. The Entry(object).Reload() command forces the object to recall database values

```
GM_MEMBERS member = DatabaseObjectContext.GM_MEMBERS.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Username == username && p.ApplicationName == this.ApplicationName);
DatabaseObjectContext.Entry(member).Reload();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is `GetDatabaseValues()`. It is used like:

```
context.Entry(/*your entry*/).GetDatabaseValues();
```

Information below is from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592677.aspx):

> The current values are the values that the properties of the entity
>   currently contain. The original values are the values that were read
>   from the database when the entity was queried. The database values are
>   the values as they are currently stored in the database. Getting the
>   database values is useful when the values in the database may have
>   changed since the entity was queried such as when a concurrent edit to
>   the database has been made by another user.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would not suggest modifying the database external to your system unless you are only doing testing and development.

The EF DbContext contains an IDisposable interface.  To release any cached data either make the Dispose calls manually or place your Database Object inside a using block.

```
        using (SchoolBriefcaseEntities datamodel = new SchoolBriefcaseEntities())
        {
            List<Compliance> compliance = new List<Compliance>();
            IList<ComplianceModel> complianceModel;
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin"))
            {
                compliance = datamodel.Compliances.Where(c => c.School.DistrictId == districtId).ToList();
            }
        }
```

This will make sure the context is cleared and recreated the next time it is used.  Make sure to do this for all your calls and not just the one you are having issues with.

Comment: Its common for more than one system to share a database.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the underlying problem here is that your `DbContext` is hanging around too long. I can tell from the fact that you are using `HttpContext` that you have a web application, and [General guidelines when working with DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj729737.aspx) include

> When working with Web applications, use a context instance per
>   request.

If you are using MVC you could use the Dispose pattern in your controller like this:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private EmployeeContext _context;

    public EmployeeController()
    {
        _context = new EmployeeContext();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_context.Employees.ToList());
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

But you really ought to be looking at dependency injection to [manage the DbContext lifetime](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/03/27/managing-entity-framework-dbcontext-lifetime-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Couple things you can do.

1. Use a new context.  The cached entities are stored in the context.  Using a new context prevents it from using the cache.
2. If you really want a global/long lasting context, you have two sub options:
   a.) always call the Reload method.  db.Entry(entity).Reload() ... this forces the context to reload that entity.
   b.) use a SqlDependency object to detect when records change and reload the entities as needed.  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-SqlDependency-5c0da0b3

Answer (score 1):

```
context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
```

called just before reload data call helped.
i can`t recreate dbcontext because i use some default settings in the DI pipeline, also i need tracking, but if you reset tracking before first call it will help to track what changed after, but disable caching just before

my method look like this:

```
public async Task<Data> GetData(int dataId)
{
    context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
    Data c = await context.Datas.Include(x => x.FieldStates).Where(x => x.Id == dataId).SingleAsync();
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a bad connection string.  Entity looked like it was doing great because it never complained until I made the context local and it finally gave me the error message.

Answer (score 0):

EF works differently with find method which gives data from context .Rest other query  are from db.If an object is already in the context, the existing object is returned (the current and original values of the object's properties in the entry are not overwritten with database values).
A query is executed against the database when:

[Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/)

It is enumerated by a foreach (C#) or For Each (Visual Basic) statement.
It is enumerated by a collection operation such as ToArray, ToDictionary, or ToList.
LINQ operators such as First or Any are specified in the outermost part of the query.
The following methods are called: the Load extension method on a DbSet, DbEntityEntry.Reload, and Database.ExecuteSqlCommand.
When results are returned from the database, objects that do not exist in the context are attached to the context. If an object is already in the context, the existing object is returned (the current and original values of the object's properties in the entry are not overwritten with database values).

When you perform a query, entities that have been added to the context but have not yet been saved to the database are not returned as part of the result set. To get the data that is in the context, see Local Data.

If a query returns no rows from the database, the result will be an empty collection, rather than null.

Answer (score 0):

As of July 27, 2023 - This Worked for me, I was facing the same caching issue :

`context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;`

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking