# Entity Framework Core 5 Reload issue

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm having issues retrieving navigation properties after an insert.

I'm saving data using this code, without setting the navigation properties that I do not want to change.
For example :

```
var entity = new MyEntity 
              {
                FirstId = 1, 
                FirstObject = null
                SecondId = 1, 
                SecondObject = null
                //...data to update
              };
_context.Update(myEntity);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Then if I try to access the navigation property it will be null (even if the main object is tracked after the savechanges).
I tried to reload the data using:

```
_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
entity = _context.Set<MyEntity>().Where(e => e.Id == entity.Id).First();
```

I've tried using reload too:

```
_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
_context.Entry(entity).Reload();
```

Still, navigation properties are null.

I am using UseLazyLoadingProxies in context configuration.
The only way to get the navigation property is to load it manually:

```
_context.Entry(entity).Reference(e=> e.FirstObject ).Load()
```

Is there a way to reload data from db (discarding all the cached data) after a SaveChanges()?

Comment: You can turn off caching at the object level for the entity.Check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828811/entity-framework-caching-issue

Comment: @marc_s Sorry, I am using EF **Core**, I've updated the issue.

Comment: Why do you use Detached entity in this case? I'm pretty sure this is the problem.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I'am using detach to try to reload the data from the db. Without detach I have the same behaviour.

Comment: `_context.Update(myEntity);` is a problem

Comment: please provide a [mcve] including your entity classes

Answer (score 3):

`Reload` does not retrieve the related data (navigation properties). And lazy loading does not work since you are creating the entity instance with `new` operator, thus it is not proxied, which is the essential for lazy loading proxies.

Detaching and retrieving the entity for the database should work (and in my test it *does* work, not sure why you claim it doesn`t):

```
_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
entity = _context.Set<MyEntity>().Where(e => e.Id == entity.Id).First();
```

But the better option is to create a proxied instance instead of `new` using one of the extension methods (either `DbContext` or `DbSet<T>`). The only drawback is that you lose object initializer syntax, but everything else will work. e.g.

```
var entity = _context.CreateProxy<MyEntity>(); // <--

entity.FirstId = 1; 
entity.SecondId = 1; 
//...data to update
_context.Update(entity);

_context.SaveChanges();

// verify it is working
var firstObject = entity.FirstObject;
var secondObject = entity.SecondObject;
Debug.Assert(firstObject != null && secondObject != null);
```

Comment: I worked like a charm, thank you! 
I don't know why reloading the data from the db does not work in my case...seems like ef keeps some sort of cache of the model.